# Function Parameter type determined at runtime?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, runtime

Is it in anyway possible ( preferably without using any third party libs), to create a function whose type is determined at runtime in C#?

e.g

```
public static void myfunc(var x)
{
     System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(x); //just an example
}
```

NOTE: I want the runtime to determine the type of the parameter and do not want to later cast the parameter to another type, as would be necessary if I use generics. e.g I don't want:

```
 myfunc<T>(T x) 
 // and then :
 MessageBox.Show((string)m);
```

UPDATE:
I am actually making a function parser for [my programming language](http://code.google.com/p/hack-programming-language/), which translates to C# code. In my language, I wanted the parameter types to be determined at runtime *always*. I was looking for some good C# feature for easy translation.
e.g
in my language syntax:

```
 function msg << x
     MessageBox.Show x
 end
```

needed to be translated to something that didn't ask for a type at compile time, but would need one at runtime.
e.g

```
public static void msg(var x)
{
     System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(x);
}
```

Comment: why do you keep referring to the **type of the function** when you really mean **type of the parameter**?

Comment: You wouldn't need that cast as all objects implement `ToString()`.  Besides, if you need to cast to a string... then the function should just take a string!  A meaningful example would be appreciated.

Comment: @codesparkle sorry, I typed the question in a hurry.

Comment: If only stackoverflow made people tell their reason before downvoting a question...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The keyword introduced for runtime binding in C# 4 is `dynamic`.

```
public static void myfunc(dynamic x)
```

This allows you to make assumptions about x that are unchecked at compile time but will fail at runtime if those assumptions prove invalid.

```
public static void MakeTheDuckQuack(dynamic duck)
{
    Console.WriteLine(duck.Quack()); 
}
```

The assumption made here is that the parameter will have a method named `Quack` that accepts no arguments and returns a value that can then be used as the argument to `Console.WriteLine`. If any of those assumptions are invalid, you will get a runtime failure.

Given classes defined as

```
class Duck
{
    public string Quack()
    {
        return "Quack!";
    }
}

class FakeDuck
{
    public string Quack()
    {
        return "Moo!";
    }
}
```

And method calls

```
MakeTheDuckQuack(new Duck());
MakeTheDuckQuack(new FakeDuck());
MakeTheDuckQuack(42);
```

The first two succeed, as runtime binding succeeds, and the third results in an exception, as `System.Int32` does not have a method named `Quack`.

Generally speaking, you would want to avoid this if possible, as you're essentially stipulating that an argument fulfill an interface of some sort without strictly defining it. If you are working in an interop scenario, then perhaps this is what you have to do. If you are working with types that you control, then you would be better served trying to achieve compile time safety via interfaces and/or base classes. You can even use different strategies (such as the *Adapter Pattern*) to make types you do not control (or cannot change) conform to a given interface.

Comment: +1 for the explanation or why *not* to use it in most scenarios and what to do instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to know the type... then you need to know the type.  You can't have your cake and eat it too.

First off, the cast in your example is unnecessary as all objects implement `ToString()`.  Instead of telling us what you think you need, tell us what problem you are trying to solve.  There is almost certainly a solution either via generics or the use of the `dynamic` keyword (though `dynamic` is rarely needed), but we need more info. If you add more I'll update this answer.

Comment: Your suggestion of the `dynamic` keyword pretty much solved the problem, but I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a type of object or, if you don't know how many items are available, you could use a [params](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) object array, i.e. `params object[] cParams`.